# How do I install forked gems on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, amazon-s3, paperclip, heroku

I'm trying to get Heroku working with European buckets on amazon s3 webserivces using the aws-s3 gem. It seems I need to install a forked version of the gem to get around the issue. However, with heroku I can only use the .gems file to install gems.

Can I use this .gems file to install forked-gems somehow?

Comment: Did you fork the gem yourself? Is it hosted anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpack the gem in your local repository, then add it to your git repository. This will copy the gem to your vendor/gems directory. Also remember to remove the gem from your .gems list to prevent Heroku from using the unwanted version.

```
#Unpacks all gems
rake gems:unpack

#Unpack a specific gem
rake gems:unpack GEM=xxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Heroku already supports Bundler even for not-Rails 3 application.
http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2010/2/17/gem_bundler_on_heroku/

You can switch to Bundler and use its syntax to have Bundler downloading the Gem from the fork.